# Spring Data JPA. Choose all posts that contain tags

Tags: sql, many-to-many, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data. I have following entities:

```
@Entity
class Post {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String message;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "POST_TAG", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "POST_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    })
    private Set<Tag> tags;
}

@Entity
class Tag {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

In PostRepository I want to have 2 methods, which:

- find all posts that contain at least one (or more) of specified tags.
- find all posts that contain all specified tags.

Something like:

```
List<Post> findByTagsContainsAnyOf(List<String> tags);
List<Post> findByTagsContainsAll(List<String> tags);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one is easy - `List<Post> findByTagsIn(List<Tag> tags)`.  Note that it is `List<Tag>` instead of `List<String>` since it is `Tag` that is mapped to `Post` and not `String`.  If you want to stick to `List<String>`, you will have to use a `@Query`.  Something like `@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.tags CONTAINS (SELECT t FROM Tag t WHERE t.name IN :tags)")` should work.

The second one will have to be done through a `@Query` by putting a join between the `Post` and `Tag` entities.

In general, JPA is merely an object-oriented API over SQL.  So, when in doubt, create the SQL and then convert it into the equivalent JPQL.  Where the JPQL is straightforward, it can be coded as the method name, relying on the Spring Data query creation framework to generate the JPQL from the method name.